# Laravel pusher.js - count user sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session, pusher

I have started with Laravel + Pusher and used the demo application from
[Pusher blog](https://blog.pusher.com/build-collaborative-note-app-using-laravel/). Here in the [source code](https://github.com/ammezie/laravel-notes/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/EditNote.vue) it is described how the user connections are counted. But I am struggling how to count the sessions by user as an additional value.

Example: Jane and John connect I get 2 for ***usersEditing.length***. If Jane connects from two browser I get 1 for ***usersEditing.length***.

```
<script>
export default {
    props: [
        'note',
    ],

    data() {
        return {
            title: this.note.title,
            body: this.note.body,
            usersEditing: [],
            status: ''
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        Echo.join(`note.${this.note.slug}`)
            .here(users => {
                this.usersEditing = users;
            })
            .joining(user => {
                this.usersEditing.push(user);
            })
            .leaving(user => {
                this.usersEditing = this.usersEditing.filter(u => u != user);
            })
            .listenForWhisper('editing', (e) => {
                this.title = e.title;
                this.body = e.body;
            })
            .listenForWhisper('saved', (e) => {
                this.status = e.status;

                // clear is status after 1s
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.status = '';
                }, 1000);
            });
    },

    methods: {
        editingNote() {
            let channel = Echo.join(`note.${this.note.slug}`);

            // show changes after 1s
            setTimeout(() => {
                channel.whisper('editing', {
                    title: this.title,
                    body: this.body
                });
            }, 1000);
        },

        updateNote() {
            let note = {
                title: this.title, 
                body:  this.body
            };

            // persist to database
            axios.patch(`/edit/${this.note.slug}`, note)
                .then(response => {
                    // show saved status
                    this.status = response.data;

                    // clear is status after 1s
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.status = '';
                    }, 1000);

                    // show saved status to others
                    Echo.join(`note.${this.note.slug}`)
                        .whisper('saved', {
                            status: response.data
                        });
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I need an additional value sessions for each user. So I can show the number of connections by user and in total.

May someone can help me here.

Thx in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Jane and John connect I get 2 for `usersEditing.length`. If Jane connects from two browser I get 1 for `usersEditing.length`.

This is because pusher's presence channels are based on unique users, rather than connections. If you wish to maintain a count of total connections or sessions, you'd need to implement something yourself.

There are a number of ways you could do this. The [`/channels` endpoint](https://pusher.com/docs/rest_api#method-get-channel) in the pusher http api allows you to retrieve `subscription_count` aswell as `user_count`.

You could configure an endpoint on your server which retrieves this data from the pusher api and broadcasts an update to a channel containing the `subscription_count`. If you call this endpoint from your client each time a subscription succeeds. Then you could maintain a subscriber count in each client.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-meeting-11');

channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
  // call your new endpoint
});
```